# Optimal way of drawing temporary object in Android OpenGL ES 1.x

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm developing a small app for Android with OpenGL ES 1.x. There is no glBegin-glEnd-functionality so one has to define vertex (and color and texcoord) arrays for the objects to be drawn, and then use matrix operations to move, scale, and rotate them. This works nicely for large objects, nothing to complain here...

However, if one want's to draw small, "temporary" objects (e.g. just a line from point A to point B), things get a bit annoying. I have thus created some small utility functions such as:

DrawHelper.drawLine(starting point, ending point)

I have noticed two possible ways to do this. My question is which of these versions is preferred? Since we are dealing with such simple helper functions, and both methods are easy and understandable, one might as well write them as good as possible from the start, even if the potential speed gain would be very low. So please no "benchmark and identify bottlenecks first".. =)

Method 1:

The draw helper has FloatBuffer containing the points (0,0,0) and (1,0,0). I draw this line every time with the appropriate modelview matrix in place transforming the two points to the desired locations.

Method 2:

The draw helper has a dummy FloatBuffer and I use FloatBuffer.put to feed in the new points every time.

Method 1 is clearly (?) better for larger objects such as circles or other geometric shapes. How about a simple line or a simple triangle?

Answer (score 1):

You always choose the method that involves fewer work. Applying a matrix multiplication is takes a lot more computations than two vector assignments. Also the matrix transformation approach sends ~2.5 times as much data to the GPU (a whole 4×4-matrix) than sending two 3-vectors.

OTOH Java adds the penality of going through a FloatBuffer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind, but I'm not sure your argument is valid for all cases. Let's say you want to draw a simple square many times in different positions. What I've read from elsewhere suggest that it's better not to change the content of the buffer but rather translate the position in OpenGL. Of course, I can't confirm this is correct, either. (Also, one could imagine that glTranslate is optimized to send only 3 arguments. I don't know..)

Comment: @user2582805: For the square at multiple positions problem you'd use instancing. And no, there's no optimization for glTranslate. glTranslate always operated on the CPU and multiplies on the current 4×4 matrix on the stack, which then must be transferred to the GPU.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll go with that then. Thanks!